# LXPanel time is wrong?

Tags: time, lubuntu, tray

I just upgraded from Lubuntu 12.10 to 13.10, and it was a nightmare. When I logged in I had nothing but a background, no tray or anything. I finally just got the tray back, but it displays the wrong time, and its static, as in it doesn't progress. I have checked that I have the NTP daemon installed; I checked the time using `date` and `hwclock`, and they are both correct. I have also checked that I am in the correct time zone using the time and date frontend. I am stumped.

Edit: Excuse me, the time does change, but only hourly; the minutes don't change at all, so it'll go from, say, 10:02 to 11:02.

Comment: This may be silly but do you have the DST on or off?

Comment: @Livinglifeback I don't know how to check that. I don't see how that would affect the minute portion of the clock.

Comment: it wouldn't.  "...but only hourly; the minutes don't change at all, so it'll go from, say, 10:02 to 11:02."  I'm not sure how to check it's probably in a menu somewhere though. Look through settings.

Comment: I don't think you can change it in Lubuntu; I think it is a setting in the BIOS. Yet the hour changing isn't the problem, so what is the point in checking the DST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. I removed the time applet, added it again and then formatted the time to my liking and it works!